# How to change SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Wizard default datasource?

Tags: sql-server-2014

Starting with SQL Server 2014 the default datasource in the Import and Export wizard is `.Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc`. Any idea how to change this?

Comment: I have the same issue in SSMS 2016.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Generate Script for Any Data base object or entire data base
By
Right Click on Data Base -> Task -> Generate Script

By Running this script data base can be create in different studio too.